# Set interleaving in RTSP with Ip camera (Onvif standard)

Tags: rtsp, rtp, ip-camera, onvif, interleave

I am working with an IP camera based on onvif standards. The scenario is the following one:

[image]

The *RTP* port and *HTTP* port are 22554 and 22280 respectively. I have no problem with this, I reroute the traffic from A to B in those ports to reach the camera. In fact, the RTP session is correctly established.

The problem comes in the *SETUP* message. Here A (which starts the session), establishes a new port (client port) for the UDP connection for video interchange. The same way, the camera also sets a new port (server port). As the server ports are not redirected in B, I am not able to receive anything.

I read that there is a possibility to used **interleaved mode** in order to use the same port used for *RTSP* messages (22554 in this case) for the video packets. But I do not know how to do this. For example, VLC tries the first option (new client-server ports) and as it does not work it successfuly setups another rtsp session with interleave mode.

I started working with this code (http://bit.ly/1Xvwqx9), which is based on Onvif libraries. But I cannot find anything regarding this aspect of interleaving.

Anyone can give me a hint?
Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. It is important to set these aspects:

```
protocol = TransportProtocol.rtsp
MediaStreamInfo.Transport transp = MediaStreamInfo.Transport.Tcp;
```